# Reemplazar Valores en DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un archivo Xlsx el cual importo a un dataframe usando Pandas, en el Xlsx existe una columna (Visit  Date) con fechas en el formato dd-mmm.-yyyy (ej. **29-abr.-2020**), este formato de fecha debe ser modificado por este formato dd-mm-yyyy (ej. **29-04-2020**), esta es parte del codigo:

```
def ProcesaArchivo():
bbdd_pais = dicc[menu_pais.get()]["Base"]
table_pais = dicc[menu_pais.get()]["Tabla"]
# ------------------------------------- LEE ARCHIVO EXCEL Y TRANSFIERA A DATAFRAME
if ruta_entry.get() == "" or menu_pais.get() == "":
    messagebox.showerror("¡Error!", "Debe Seleccionar un País y un Archivo")
else:
    df = pd.read_excel(open(ruta_entry.get(), 'rb'), sheet_name=pd.ExcelFile(ruta_entry.get()).sheet_names[0])
    ***df = df.replace(dic_fecha, inplace=True)***
    if df["Country Name"].head(1).values == [menu_pais.get().upper()]:
        status_extraccion.config(text="Total rows en el archivo: {0}".format(len(df)))
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("¡Error!", "El archivo no corresponde al país seleccionado")
        quit()
```

Para realizar la sustitución estoy usando un diccionario que esta conformado así:

```
dic_fecha={'-ene.-': '-1-','-feb.-': '-2-','-mar.-': '-3-','-abr.-': '-4-','-may.-': '-5-','-Jun.-': '-6-','-Jul.-': '7-', '-ago.-': '-8-','-sep.-': '-9-','-oct.-': '-10-','-nov.-': '11-','-dic.-': '-12-'}
```

Estoy usando Replace pero creo que no la estoy usando de forma correcta porque no se realizar la modificación en la columna.

Aca hay un ejemplo del archivo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLlmzUx0mALceX5ocKfv-9yUAJW6hwdsiy-rcwOLwsM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cuando uses `inplace=True` no reasignes:

  ```
  df = df.replace(dic_fecha, inplace=True)
  ^^^^
  ^^^^
  ```

  si se pasa el argumento `inplace=True` el método retorna `None`.
- Considera aplicar `replace` solo sobre la columna objetivo.
- Debes usar `regex=True` o en caso contrario buscará la coincidencia completa directa.

---

```
dic_fecha = {
    'ene.': '1', 'feb.': '2', 'mar.': '3', 'abr.': '4',
    'may.': '5', 'jun.': '6', 'jul.': '7', 'ago.': '8',
    'sep.': '9', 'oct.': '10', 'nov.': '11','dic.': '12'
    }

df = pd.read_excel(ruta_entry.get(), sheet_name=0)
df["Visit Date"].replace(dic_fecha, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Para tu archivo de ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> df["Visit Date"]
>
> 0      29-1-2020
> 1      29-2-2020
> 2      29-3-2020
> 3      27-4-2020
> 4      27-5-2020
> 5      27-6-2020
> 6      27-7-2020
> 7      27-8-2020
> 8      27-9-2020
> 9     29-10-2020
> 10    27-11-2020
> 11    27-12-2020
> 12     27-5-2020
> 13     26-5-2020
> 14     26-5-2020
> 15     26-5-2020
> 16     28-5-2020
> 17     28-5-2020
> 18     28-5-2020
> 19     25-5-2020
> 20     26-5-2020
> 21     27-5-2020
> 22     29-5-2020
> 23     29-5-2020
> 24     26-5-2020
> 25     29-5-2020
> 26     26-5-2020
> ```